# Why twilio not able to call action url from gather command?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, twilio, twilio-twiml

I'm writing an IVR application using Twilio in .net MVC.Here is my code

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    [System.Web.Http.Route("api/VoiceMain/ReceiveCall")]
    public HttpResponseMessage ReceiveCall()
    {
        var response = new VoiceResponse();
        response.Say("Welcome, How can I help you?", voice: "alice", language: "en-AU");
        var gather = new Gather(
            input: new[] { Gather.InputEnum.Speech }.ToList(),
        action: new Uri("/api/Voice/ProcessCall?ConversationId=0"), method: Twilio.Http.HttpMethod.Post, language: "en-AU", timeout: 3);
        response.Append(gather);
        var res = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        res.Content = new StringContent(response.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
        return res;
    }
```

And here is my ProcessCall method

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    [System.Web.Http.Route("api/Voice/ProcessCall")]
    public HttpResponseMessage ProcessCall(VoiceRequest request,int ConversationId=0)
    {
          string inputQuery;
          inputQuery = request.SpeechResult;
    }
```

I am sending SpeechResult text to dialogflow for further processing.
In twilio webhook when i use ngrok url like below whole process goes smooth
[image]

I hosted this api on azure, so instead of ngrok url when i use azure url as webhook in twilio like below

[image]

twilio is giving error..

[image]

Can someone help me in this as I am new in twilio..Thanks

Comment: 500 sounds like it called your method, but your method threw an exception.

Comment: I put logs in my ProcessCall method.From which i got that it is not calling my ProcessCall method.

Comment: If you change twilio to instead call `/api/VoiceMain/mjwills` what http status does it return?

Comment: as i mentioned instead of azure url if i locally deply application and put ngrok url before before /api/VoiceMain..it is returning 200

Comment: And if you try `mjwills` on `Azure`? In particular I want to know if it 500s or 404s.

Comment: twilio is returning 500 status code

Comment: Did you try changing the Twilio POST method to a GET method, to see if that changes anything? It is in the screenshot you provided. Certainly something on the Azure configuration side.

Comment: Have you checked, that azure endpoint returning Ok response, when you call it manually by postman or swagger?